# How to place a pagination on the footer, showing the number of pages from 1 to x

Tags: html, css, tumblr

this is the theme http://static.tumblr.com/taepiis/sxUln8432/theme3.txt
the right one.

I want to use a pagination that shows the number of pages that my blog have in the footer.
how can i use and where do i place it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [the tumblr docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#navigation) to learn more about how to write your own custom pagination.

In particular, [these tumblr docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/localizing_themes) give instructions on how to output the total number of pages in your blog, including what number the current page is:

```
{lang:Page CurrentPage of TotalPages}   Page ___ of ___        
{lang:Page CurrentPage of TotalPages 2} Page ___ <em>of</em> ___
```

I also found this code from the [Effector tumblr theme](http://effectortheme.tumblr.com/) that does this kind of pagination.  It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's a start:

```
{block:Pagination}
<div id="pagination">
    <div class="nextprev">
        {block:PreviousPage}<a class="prev" href="{PreviousPage}">{/block:PreviousPage}<span>&larr; {lang:Newer}</span>{block:PreviousPage}</a>{/block:PreviousPage} <span class="sep">&bull;</span>
        {block:NextPage}<a class="next" href="{NextPage}">{/block:NextPage}<span>{lang:Older} &rarr;</span>{block:NextPage}</a>{/block:NextPage}
    </div>
    <div class="current-page">{lang:Page CurrentPage of TotalPages 2}</div>
</div><!--/#pagination -->
{/block:Pagination}
{block:PermalinkPagination}
<div id="pagination" class="single-pagination">
    <div class="nextprev">
        {block:NextPost}<a class="prev" href="{NextPost}">{/block:NextPost}<span>&larr; {lang:Previous}</span>{block:NextPost}</a>{/block:NextPost} <span class="sep">&bull;</span>
        {block:PreviousPost}<a class="next" href="{PreviousPost}">{/block:PreviousPost}<span>{lang:Next} &rarr;</span>{block:PreviousPost}</a>{/block:PreviousPost}
    </div>
</div><!--/#pagination -->
{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

Also, please remember to accept answers if they are useful and help solve your problem.